# Passing a 3D array ( 2D array of strings ) to a function and edit it there

Tags: c, arrays, 3d

i spent a good amount of time searching for this answer and even though i found some similar answers, nothing seemed to work for me, got me very frustrated :/

What i want to do is very simple. I want to create a 2D array of strings in 1 function ( 2D array of string is 3D array of chars ) and i want to pass it to another function and edit it there globaly. I would be happy if 1 dimension could by dynamic but i had soo much trouble with malloc, i would even accept an option where all 3 dimensions are static. Just as long as i could pass reference to it to function, fill it in that function and then use it in main. I am looking for a solution without struct.

i managed to pass 3d array of chars just as long as i was adding chars simple by array[5][5][5] and then void function(char array[5][5][5]). But i couldnt add strings this way. I am really in a hurry. If you dont want to answer my question then just give me a link to where this is explained and i will figure it out.

EDIT:

```
  void function(char* array[5][5]) { 
        array[0][0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5); array[0][0] = "something" 
    } 

    int main() {
       char* array[5][5]; function(array); printf("%s", array[0][0]); 
    }
```

Comment: Show your achievements.

Comment: Note that `void foo(char* array[5][5])` is the same as `void foo(char* (*array)[5])`: Array arguments decay into pointers to their first element, both in the call and in the function signature. I. e. your compiler won't bark if you used `char* array[1][5]; function(array);` to call your function, but your program could crash or do other unpleasant stuff.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

void doit ( char ***array, int x, int y, int z ) {
   int i,j,k;
   for ( i=0; i<x; i++ ) {
      for ( j=0; j<y; j++ ) {
         snprintf(array[i][j],z,"this is %d/%d",i,j);
      }
   }
}

void main ( int c, char**v ) {
   int i,j,k,x=3,y=5,z=17;
   char ***array = (char***)malloc(sizeof(char**)*x);
   for ( i=0; i<x; i++ ) {
      array[i] = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*y);
      for ( j=0; j<y; j++ ) {
         array[i][j] = (char*)malloc(z);
      }
   }
   doit(array,x,y,z);
   for ( i=0; i<x; i++ ) {
      for ( j=0; j<y; j++ ) {
         printf("%d/%d %s\n",i,j,array[i][j]);
      }
   }
   for ( i=0; i<x; free(array[i++]) ) {
      for ( j=0; j<y; free(array[i][j++]) );
   }
   free(array);
}
```

With C++, the same could be achieved in a much more readable way.

Comment: My god, it seems that there are infinite ways to solve the same problem. There is so much i still have to learn about C. Thank you all for your help and sorry for taking your time.

Comment: You better learn C++. You now have the choice between my potentially confusing malloc party and cmasters elegant use of variable sized arrays on stack which work for C99 and higher. In C++ you can have a solution that is both simple and supported by standard compilers. If ever again you have to write a program, C++ might save lots of work.

Comment: C vs. C++ is an endless debate. In the area of multidimensional arrays, C rules. (I still use C++ most of the time, though :-) )

Answer (score 1):

The easy way:

```
void foo(size_t height, size_t width, size_t length, char (*stringMatrix)[width][length]) {
    for(size_t y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for(size_t x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                stringMatrix[y][x][i] = /*whatever*/;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    size_t height = 5, width = 7, length = 9;

    //use either of the following two lines
    char stringMatrix[height][width][length];
    //char (*stringMatrix)[width][length] = malloc(height * sizeof(*stringMatrix));

    foo(height, width, length, stringMatrix);

    //if you used malloc(), don't forget to free your matrix:
    //free(stringMatrix);
}
```

The better way:

```
//Fills the matrix with malloc'd strings.
void foo(size_t height, size_t width, char* (*stringMatrix)[width]) {
    for(size_t y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for(size_t x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            stringMatrix[y][x] = malloc(/* the length that you need for this string */);
            //initialize the string in stringMatrix[y][x]
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    size_t height = 5, width = 7;

    //use either of the following two lines
    char* stringMatrix[height][width];
    //char* (*stringMatrix)[width] = malloc(height * sizeof(*stringMatrix));

    foo(height, width, stringMatrix);

    //Cleanup
    for(size_t y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for(size_t x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            free(stringMatrix[y][x]);
        }
    }
    //if you used malloc(), don't forget to free your matrix:
    //free(stringMatrix);
}
```

Both approaches use a true multidimensional array, which is passed to the function as a pointer to the first element of the first dimension of the array. The difference is, that the first version uses a true 3D array, while the second version uses a 2D array of `char*`, which have to be allocated in the function for each string with which you fill the matrix.

Why is the second version better? Simply because it does not impose a limit on the size of the strings that you can handle. It may seem inconvenient to use dynamically allocated strings everywhere, but the truth is that almost every fixed length buffer is a bug that is just waiting to happen. Sooner or later you will get a usecase that exceeds the limit, and your program explodes.

With the POSIX-2008 standard we also have a variety of string handling functions available that produce ready made malloc'd strings, like `strdup()`, `getline()`, `asprintf()`, etc. If you use these, a lot of the hassle of allocating strings to fit goes away.